# Learning generalized functions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

What is the best book to learn generalized functions and what prerequisites are needed? I would like a book that helps build intuition but it rigorous enough and not overly complex. 
My background is engineering and I am more or less familiar with real and complex analysis, algebra, differential equations, Fourier and Laplace transforms.

Comment: I couldn't say which is "the best book". About general points, for example see :  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunction.html or: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function

Comment: You may want to check http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math581w19/ (there is a .pdf of notes) and the Appendix of Lax's Functional Analysis that contains an introduction. I think a proper background is some basic topology, analysis and functional analysis.